# How to enable editing of HTML files in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Using IDEA 13 EAP, whenever I select an HTML file for editing, a blank window is displayed with 'Enter your URL here', rather than the HTML within the file. Is this intended behaviour?

[image]

Comment: when do you see this message - when opening HTML file in editor? Can you attach a screencast that shows up the problem? Also, do you have any additional (non-bundled) plugins installed?

Comment: Yes, when opening the file in an editor. I am using the Play2.0 plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that *.html files were assigned to the 'webbrowser' file type in the IDE settings. After changing this, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "*.html" is not associated with filetype "HTML".

In "Editor" - "File Types" - "HTML" - "File name patterns", there was none. After adding "*.html", I am now able to edit HTML file(after clicking it, the text content shows in editor panel).